# SQL - Select column with certain value in it and other random values

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Let me say i have a table called `test` with the following data

```
+---------+-----------------+
| id      | t_number        |
+---------+-----------------+
|       1 | 864291100247345 |
|       2 | 355488020906457 |
|       3 | 864296100098739 |
|       4 | 864296100098325 |
|       5 | 864296100119956 |
```

What i want to do is to be able to write a `select` statement that returns a 3 rows with two random values and one mandatory value from the `t_number` column
for example if the mandatory value is `864291100247345` the output should something like below

```
+---------+-----------------+
| id      | t_number        |
+---------+-----------------+
|       1 | 864291100247345 |
|       2 | 355488020906457 |
|       4 | 864296100098325 |
```

OR

```
+---------+-----------------+
| id      | t_number        |
+---------+-----------------+
|       1 | 864291100247345 |
|       3 | 864296100098739 |
|       4 | 864296100098325 |
```

I have tried the below query but it's not yielding the output i expect, in a sense that it does return a result but without the mandatory value

```
SELECT * FROM test WHERE t_number = 864291100247345 OR id LIMIT 3;
```

What is the best way to go about this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order by`:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM test 
ORDER BY (t_number = 864291100247345) DESC,
         rand()
LIMIT 3;
```

This returns the mandatory number first and then random numbers after that.

MySQL treats boolean values (the result of the `=` expression) as numbers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  So the first expression in the `order by` sorts the result set with the "true" conditions first, followed by the others.

Comment: thank you, your solution is working but i can't seem to understand how `(t_number = 864291100247345) DESC` is acceptable in an `ORDER BY` clause